Unable to Upload Video to YouTube in ASP.NET Core Project using Google API
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project using .NET 8 where I need to upload a video to YouTube in private mode . I've implemented the video upload functionality, but I'm encountering issues when trying to upload the video. Specifically, I'm seeing an error:
I have set up OAuth 2.0 for authentication and have followed the Google API documentation for uploading videos to YouTube. However, I'm facing a "mismatch redirect URI" error when attempting to authorize the application.and im excepting this error should be resolved .
Code :
https://github.com/Venkatesh-Pudi/YoutudeVideoUploader.git
#asp.net-core #google-api #youtube-api #oauth-2.0 #redirect-uri c# #authentication #google-developer-console

first get the redirect uri from the google api console and reset that in appsettings.json file. could you share your program.cs file?

The redirect uri must match is a common error and easy to fix you just need to add the redirect uri the error is telling you is missing to your project in google developer console.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ

please edit your question and include [example]

I have shared the Program.cs file. Could you please review it and assist me with resolving the issue,  @JalpaPanchal
https://github.com/Venkatesh-Pudi/YoutudeVideoUploader.git

your code looks good. have you checked your "Authorized redirect URIs" in your Google API Console is correctly set with the local url lets says http://localhost:7878/authorize/. make sure you have set the redirect uris and client secrete in your project correctly. if it still doe snot work you could try regenerating your OAuth credentials in the Google API Console and update the credentials.json file.
